# Can't find the images uploaded by php script

Tags: php

I have write a script to allow the users upload the images to the server, the script  works fine on local environment and images are uploaded to tmp folder first then moved to specific location after.
But when i live the site and users have uploaded there pictures, but that are not uploaded properly, only the images names that are coming from the database. 
I also checked the tmp folder is not created on the live serve. 
How i can recover those images, where that are gone ?

Here is the code snipet

```
$absolutedir        = dirname(__FILE__);
$dir                        = '/tmp/';
$serverdir          = $absolutedir.$dir;
$tmp    = explode(',',$_POST['data']);
$imgdata                = base64_decode($tmp[1]);

$explosion = explode('.',$_POST['name']);
$exlosion = explode('.',$_POST['name']);
$end_of_explosion = end( $explosion );
$extension          = strtolower($end_of_explosion);
$filename   = basename(substr($_POST['name'],0,-(strlen($extension) + 1))).'.'.substr(sha1(time()),0,6).'.'.$extension;
$handle = fopen($serverdir.$filename,'w');
fwrite($handle, $imgdata);
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: where is the code??

Comment: Can you provide a little code snippet you are using please ?

Comment: why are you uisng $_POST for file

Comment: Your approach is more trouble than it's worth I think. I suggest you start over and implement uploads correctly, using PHP's built-in methods and `$_FILES` array. Read http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php to get you started

Answer (score 0):

you probability find that file on DOCUMENT_ROOT. i don't know externally reason. but i had a same issue and files are created on DOCUMENT_ROOT.
or if your code is on Linux based system just make sure permission table are configured correctly?

this is just hunch not a perfect solution.